# How to subscribe or intercept "policy updates" in the WSO2 Identify Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

According to the documentation, Notifications for policy updates is supported for "XACML 2.0/3.0", but I could not find additional information about it. In general we need to either subscribe or intercept policy updates taking place in our WSO2IS being triggered via API calls or Admin Console.

Any hints will be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Policies can be stored as registry resources. Subscriptions can be created for any updates to the resources along with the required notification method. For more details on subscription to registry resources, pls refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Managing+Subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for your help Gillian, I'll explore this option.

Comment: Gillian, the WSO2 Governance Registry looks like a separate product. Can subscriptions be managed within the WSO2 Identity server itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two ways that can be achieved this..  One way would be installed the registry resource features in to WSO2IS as mentioned in above.  But there is some better way to do.. identity server provides some extension for it. You can read [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/03/14/policy-store-notifications-with-identity-server/) for more details..  it is more flexible way than using above